# How to edit data from form field?

Tags: php, edit, form-fields

when i edit data from form field it only select/fetch one word though form field has many words/ or complete sentence where is wrong?

```
 <?php
 //getting id from url
 $id = $_GET['id'];

 //selecting data associated with this particular id
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM list WHERE id=$id");

  while($res = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
  $Test_name = $res['Test_name'];

  }
  ?>

 <form name="form1" method="post" action="edit.php">
    <table border="0">


        <tr> 
            <td>Test Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Test_name" value=<?php echo 
             $Test_name;?>></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="id" value=<?php echo 
             $_GET['id'];?>></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update"></td>
        </tr

    </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks @KirkBeard :-)

Comment: The time to upgrade from `mysql_` to `mysqli_` and implement prepared statements with placeholders is: Now, if not Yesterday.  Validating and sanitizing user provided data is vital; research these topics and improve your code.  The accepted answer uses a workaround instead of just telling you to quote your values.  This question is Off-topic: typo. (Your `id` value is not truncated because it has no spaces.)

Comment: I had answered first, check the time :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TextArea for long value edit.
Hope below example will help you.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="edit.php">
    <table border="0">


        <tr> 
            <td>Test Name</td>
            <td><textarea name="Test_name" value=<?php echo 
             $Test_name;?>><?php echo 
             $Test_name;?></textarea></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="id" value=<?php echo 
             $_GET['id'];?>></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update"></td>
        </tr

    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Use `textarea` for long value edit.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="edit.php">
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>Test Name</td>
            <td><textarea name="Test_name" value=<?php echo
                $Test_name;?>><?php echo
                    $Test_name;?></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="id" value=<?php echo
                $_GET['id'];?>></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update"></td>
        </tr
    </table>
</form>
```